# Equation containing Tikz Pictures

Tags: tikz-trees

I am trying to typeset an equation where the equated elements are expressions using binary trees. But the layout of my equation is terrible, the brackets are incorrectly placed and binary trees are everywhere. I hope someone can help me making a nicer equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\oddsidemargin 43pt
\textheight 20.4 cm
\textwidth 14.0 cm
\parskip 6.8 pt
\parindent 12 pt
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\hspace{-12mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
      level distance=7.5mm,
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
      level 2/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
      level 3/.style={sibling distance=7.5mm},
      level 4/.style={sibling distance=3.75mm}
      baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
      \node (a) {$a$}
        child {node (b1) {$b$}
            child{node(c1) {$c$}
                child{node(d1) {$T$}}
                child{node(d2) {$F$}}
            }
            child{node(c1) {$c$}
                child{node(d1) {$T$}}
                child{node(d2) {$F$}}
            }
        }
        child {node (b2) {$F$}}
        ;
      \end{tikzpicture}
      = T \land \left (
      \begin{tikzpicture}[%
      level distance=7.5mm,
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
      level 2/.style={sibling distance=7.5mm},
      level 3/.style={sibling distance=3.75mm}
      baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
      \node (a) {$a$}
        child {node (b1) {$b$}
            child{node(c1) {$T$}}
            child{node(c1) {$T$}}
        }
        child {node (b2) {$F$}}
        ;
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \land
      \begin{tikzpicture}[%
      level distance=7.5mm,
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
      level 2/.style={sibling distance=7.5mm},
      level 3/.style={sibling distance=3.75mm}
      baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
      \node (a) {$c$}
        child {node (b1) {$T$}}
        child {node (b2) {$F$}}
        ;
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \right ) 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing three commas  - like this: `...ance=3.75mm},`

Comment: You can wrap `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` around the `tikzpicture` environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution with use of the `forest` and `adjustbox` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\forestset{
  default preamble={
    for tree={l sep=3mm, s sep=2mm, math content}}
            }
    \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{forest}
[a
    [b,fit=band
        [c
            [T]
            [F]
        ]
        [c
            [T]
            [F]
        ]
    ]
    [F]
]
      \end{forest}}
      = T \land \left(\hspace{-1.2em}
    \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{forest}
[a
    [b
        [T]
        [F]
    ]
    [F]
]
      \end{forest}}
      \land
      \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{forest}
[c
    [T]
    [F]
]
      \end{forest}}
      \right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant of [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517119/), which does the alignment with `baseline` rather than loading `adjustbox`. (I hasten to add that I know no reason not to load `adjustbox`, so this isn't any particular advantage in general.)

I've aligned them a bit differently, because I find trees easier to read this way, but this is very much a matter of preference, context and content.

```
\documentclass[border=9pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \forestset{
    default preamble={
      for tree={l sep'=3mm, s sep'=2mm, math content},
      delay={!r1.baseline}
    }
  }
      \begin{forest}
      [a
        [b,fit=band
          [c
            [T]
            [F]
          ]
          [c
            [T]
            [F]
          ]
        ]
        [F]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  = T \land \left(
    \begin{forest}
      [a
        [b
          [T]
          [F]
        ]
        [F]
      ]
      \end{forest}
      \land
        \begin{forest}
          [c
            [T]
            [F]
          ]
      \end{forest}
      \right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned trees]